# VB.NET Excel Run .XLA File

Tags: vb.net, excel

I had the following code.

I am trying to call EntFunc2.xla and load it into the Excel1.xls but it seems like not successful. May I know how can I really run the xla file in my Excel directly through VB.NET codes?

```
   Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
   Dim xlWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
   Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
   Dim xlCells As Excel.Range = Nothing
   xlApp = New Excel.Application
   xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
   xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks
   xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open("C:\Excel1.xls")
   xlApp.Visible = True
   xlApp.Run("P:\MASTER\EntFunc2.xla")
```

Comment: When you say it's not successful, do you mean that you're getting an error, that nothing is happening, or that you're getting unexpected results?

Comment: In my Excel1.xls, there is a cell to call the formula in EntFunc2.xla. When I trying to call the EntFunc2.xla through my codes, it give me #NAME? which is incorrect. However, when I try to open the EntFunc2.xla manually after my Excel1.xls being generated, it give me a correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the XLA as if it was an ordinary workbook

```
xlWorkbooks.Open("P:\MASTER\EntFunc2.xla")
```

Comment: May I know which part of my codes should add in the above codes?

Comment: probably a good idea to add it as the first workbook you open